# Gretty build fails with SpringBoot

Tags: maven, spring-boot, gradle, jetty, gretty

I'm building out a REST API for a personal project (project name: no-hold), built in Java.
I'm using Spring Boot and Jetty to do so, and deploying it onto Google App Engine as a WAR.

However, when I attempt to run `mvn jetty:run-exploded`, I get the following error:

```
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:9.4.3.v20170317:run-exploded (default-cli) @ no-hold ---
    [INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: no-hold
    [INFO] Logging initialized @3732ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
    [INFO] Context path = /
    [INFO] Tmp directory = /Users/lucasjohnston/code/no-hold/target/tmp
    [INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
    [INFO] Web overrides =  none
    [INFO] jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
    [INFO] Scanning elapsed time=575ms
    [WARNING] Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.JettyWebAppContext@3c0bbc9f{/,file:///Users/lucasjohnston/code/no-hold/target/no-hold-1.0-SNAPSHOT/,UNAVAILABLE}{/Users/lucasjohnston/code/no-hold/target/no-hold-1.0-SNAPSHOT}
    org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.scanForAnnotations (AnnotationConfiguration.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration.configure (AnnotationConfiguration.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure (WebAppContext.java:512)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1437)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:799)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:261)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:432)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart (ContextHandlerCollection.java:161)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:419)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:460)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.execute (JettyRunWarExplodedMojo.java:69)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiException: Multiple exceptions
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:878)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:837)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error scanning entry META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class from jar file:///Users/lucasjohnston/code/no-hold/target/no-hold-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:891)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:837)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
        at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> (Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.scanClass (AnnotationParser.java:959)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJarEntry (AnnotationParser.java:940)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parseJar (AnnotationParser.java:887)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationParser.parse (AnnotationParser.java:837)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$ParserTask.call (AnnotationConfiguration.java:159)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration$1.run (AnnotationConfiguration.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745)
```

When deployed to GAE, a 403 Forbidden is thrown.

This is my current setup:

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <groupId>com.bytelucas.flex.nohold</groupId>
  <artifactId>no-hold</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <appengine.maven.plugin>1.3.2</appengine.maven.plugin>
    <jetty.maven.plugin>9.4.3.v20170317</jetty.maven.plugin>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.maven.plugin}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${appengine.maven.plugin}</version>
        <configuration>
          <!-- deploy configuration -->
<!--
          <deploy.promote>true</deploy.promote>                           <!~~ DEFAULT value ~~>
          <deploy.stopPreviousVersion>true</deploy.stopPreviousVersion>   <!~~ DEFAULT value ~~>
 -->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:+'
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE"
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com'             // Google's mirror of Maven Central
    }

    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'
apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.+'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jsp:9.+'
    compile group: 'org.akhikhl.gretty', name: 'gretty-spring-boot-plugin-commons', version: '0.0.24'
    compile group: "com.twilio.sdk", name: "twilio", version: "7.17.+"
}

gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = '/'
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'
    springBoot = true
    springBootVersion = '2.0.1.RELEASE'
}

appengine {
    deploy {
        stopPreviousVersion = true
        promote = true
    }

}

group = 'com.bytelucas.appengine'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

Api.java:

```
package com.bytelucas.appengine.nohold;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ApiController.class)
public class Api extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Api.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Api.class);
  }
}
```

ApiController.java

```
package com.bytelucas.appengine.nohold;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ApiController {
  @GetMapping("/api")
  public Name apiGetRequest(
      @NotNull @RequestParam(value="name") String name) {
    return new Name(name);
  }
}
```

I've sort of hit a brick wall at this point so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are using dependencies with Java 9 JEP-238 (MultiRelease Jar Files) support.

> `META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/ProcessIdUtil.class from jar file:///Users/lucasjohnston/code/no-hold/target/no-hold-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar`

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238

Support for JEP-238 in Jetty was first introduced in Jetty 9.4.7.v20170914.

JEP-238 Support in Jetty has had many updates since then.

The last release with JEP-238 support bug fixes was Jetty 9.4.9.v20180320

Comment: Still getting '/ ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@64bfbc86{/,file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/,UNAVAILABLE}{/root.war} [failed]' on deployment to GAE